# Android. How to determine screen orientation if application supports only portrait mode?

Tags: android, bitmap, orientation, landscape, portrait

My Android application works only in portrait orientation. Landscape mode is disabled with

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT).
```

But i have a dialog with a signature view (custom view) and a user uses it for drawing his signature. It gives a bitmap as a result. I also have an ImageView for saved signature preview which displays the bitmap described above. A user can hold his device as he wants while drawing a signature. So, my application should rotate resulting bitmap according to current screen position. For instance, a user draws his signature with angle = 90 degrees and i want to rotate the bitmap at 90 degrees and my application will display the signature bitmap in portrait mode properly. The problem is that only portrait mode is supported and the following approaches doesn't work:

```
int rotation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
```

or

```
int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getOrientation();
```

The result for these statements is always 0.

So, how i can get a current position of device in case an orientation changing is disabled?

Comment: you could use the hardware sensors to get the precise orientation of the phone and determine which way it is facing

Comment: As i know hardware sensors use callback onChanged() and i can get a value only when this callback happens. Also, the sensor will give me raw values and it promises to be a huge workload to process them in more convenient values like Surface.ROTATION_0, Surface.ROTATION_90, Surface.ROTATION_180, Surface.ROTATION_270.

Answer (score 1):

You could make your dialog a separate activity, and make it not restricted to portrait orientation.

Comment: Unfortunately i can't make it not restricted to portrait orientation since it's a customer's requirement. And creating a new activity instead a dialog is not a way out for me because my signature view is on a custom pager with a couple of fragments and a restoring its state after launching a new activity is not that easy.